Finding the inverse function in explicit form
For the following function:
$$x = A(1+y)^{1/3} - B (1+y)^{2/3} + 
\frac{C}{\sqrt{(1+y)}}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\sqrt{(1+y)}$$
Here, $x=x(y,t)$ and $y=y(x,t)$, and the other terms are constants. I want to obtain the expression of $y$ explicitly in terms of $x$. In other words, I like to get the inverse function, from $x(y,t)$ to $y(x,t)$.
I am trying to rewrite it in the form:
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}u^{1/2} + Eu^{5/6} + Fu^{7/6} + Gxu^{1/2} =0
\quad \text{[here, $u=1+y$]} \\
\implies & \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial t^2} + Ev^{5/3} + Fv^{7/3} + Gxv =0
\quad \text{[here, $v=u^{1/2}$]}
\end{align}
But how can I solve it? Or is there any other effective way to tackle it?

It's unlikely that you can without extra information. You have a second-order differential equation for $y$, which typically requires you to be able to transform it into a known class before you can solve it, and without knowing what $x$ is that's going to be impossible.

@ConMan What extra information would be helpful?

Literally knowing $x(t)$ is probably the one thing that you need.

Yes, I get your point now. But I don't have the information yet. If I get to know any further info, I will update the question.
